# How to round to two digits in python for timing

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I am writing this program and I want to round the time that gets printed off to the tens place.

```
from timeit import default_timer
        start= default_timer()
#This is where i have a bunch of other code that isn't relavant
duration = default_timer()-start
print (duration)
```

I tried to use round(duration, 2) before I printed it and that didn't work. I just don't really know how to round it. There's probably a simple answer but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score -2):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points). This is one answer provided in that link:

```
from timeit import default_timer
import time

start= default_timer()
time.sleep(2)  # Insert your code here.
duration = default_timer()-start
print("{0:.2f}".format(duration))
```

Comment: If it’s a dupe, flag the question as a dupe and/or comment rather than add an answer saying it’s a dupe

Comment: My bad, couldn't comment cos of rep. Thanks.

Comment: It gives me 2.00  every time I run it @Arex